# Prove\Disprove: $TS=ST$, and $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ Then $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $S$.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Prove or Disprove:**

---

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension, and $T,S:V\to V$ linear maps.
Suppose $T\circ S=S\circ T$, and that $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$ where $\dim V_{\lambda}=1.$
Then $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather use mathix notation.
We have $TS\mathbf{v}=ST\mathbf{v}=\lambda S\mathbf{v}$, in other words, $T(S\mathbf{v})=\lambda(S\mathbf{v})$, so $S\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ too, but $\dim V_\lambda=1$ so $S\mathbf{v}=\lambda_1\mathbf{v}$ for some $\lambda_1$ hence the desired result.

Comment: That is elegant, thank you!